# La consulta PDO no se ejecuta, ni reemplaza las etiquetas en el bindParam

Tags: php, pdo

Estoy haciendo un formulario de registro con PDO, lo estoy haciendo con el método de poner las etiquetas de los campos, y luego dar el valor de los campos a las etiquetas, pero al ejecutar la consulta, es decir, al enviar el formulario veo que no ejecuta la consulta y cuando la imprimo veo que no pone los valores de los campos sino solo el nombre de las etiquetas. Entonces allí tendría un doble problema, ya que la consulta no se ejecuta y los valores no se reemplazan.

PHP

```
require "Conexion.php";
$queriRegistrar=$conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO `usuarios`(`NOMBRE_USUARIO`, `NOMBRE`, `APELLIDO`, `CORREO`, `CLAVE`, `DIRECCION`, `TELEFONO`,`ID_GENERO_FK`,`ID_TIPO_USUARIO_FK`) 
          VALUES (:username,:nombre,:apellido,:correo,:clave,:direccion,:telefono,:genero,1)");
          $queriRegistrar->bindParam(':username',$_POST['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $queriRegistrar->bindParam(':nombre',$_POST['nombre'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $queriRegistrar->bindParam(':apellido',$_POST['apellido'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $queriRegistrar->bindParam(':correo',$_POST['correo'], PDO::PARAM_STR,null,null);
          $queriRegistrar->bindParam(':clave',$_POST['clave'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $queriRegistrar->bindParam(':direccion',$_POST['direccion'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $queriRegistrar->bindParam(':telefono',$_POST['telefono'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
          $queriRegistrar->bindParam(':genero',$_POST['genero'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
          
          $queriRegistrar->execute();
```

---

Conexión

```
 try{
     $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=calzados', 'root', '');
  }catch(Exception $e){
     die("Error" .$e->getMessage());
  }
```

Comment: traduce al español, pues estás en SO en español

Comment: Podrias colocar como tienes tu bd? y tu formulario, para descartar que sea un problema en el envío

Comment: La solución NO va en la pregunta sino en la respuesta por favor quítala de ahi y ubicala abajo donde corresponde

Comment: no se como se responde :(

Comment: Ubica debajo de tu pregunta la sección de respuestas, ahi mero va tu solución, lee además [answer]

Comment: note que hay 9 valores que eliges editar pero luego solo editas 8. No se por qué no sale un error pero la consulta no va a ser exitosa si no lo corriges

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se me ocurre de primeras es añadirle los atributos de excepciones y errores a la conexión PDO para que muestre posibles fallos al ejecutar la sentencia SQL de la consulta.

```
 try{
    $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=calzados', 'root', '');
    $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  }catch(Exception $e){
     die("Error" .$e->getMessage());
  }
```